# hash format error! using routing

Tags: sapui5

I have developed an OpenUI5 app ant it works fine!

But **every time that I invoke the routing** I have this message:

```
2015-07-15 16:15:45 hash format error! The current Hash: /line/01 -    
  log   
  error 
  onHashChange  
  detectHashChange  
  jQuery.event.dispatch 
  jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

[image]

It is not a blocking problem but it is annoying because it dirty and fills thi debug console..!

To call the router I write:

```
this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
this.router.navTo("activities", {
            "id_line": '01'
        });
```

and this is the routing file:

```
routes: [
                ...
                {
                    pattern: "line/{id_line}",
                    name: "activities",
                    target: ["master_search", "detail_activities"]
                },
                ...
        ],

 targets: {
                master_search: {
                    viewName: "UniversalMenu",
                    viewLevel: 1,
                    controlAggregation: "masterPages"
                }
                ,
                detail_activities: {
                    viewName: "DetailActivity",
                    viewLevel: 4

                }
                ...
            }
```

Edit: this is a snippet where I use `jQuery.sap.history`

```
jQuery.sap.require("jquery.sap.history");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.InstanceManager");

sap.ui.controller("ui5bp.view.App", {

    getDefaultPage : function () {
        return "Menu";
    },

    onInit : function () {
        var historyDefaultHandler = function (navType) {
            if (navType === jQuery.sap.history.NavType.Back) {
                //this.navBack(this.getDefaultPage());
            } else {
                this.navTo(this.getDefaultPage(), null, false);
            }
        };

        var historyPageHandler = function (params, navType) {
            if (!params || !params.id) {
                jQuery.sap.log.error("invalid parameter: " + params);
            } else {
                if (navType === jQuery.sap.history.NavType.Back) {
                    this.navBack(params.id);
                } else {
                    this.navTo(params.id, params.data, false);
                }
            }
        };

        jQuery.sap.history({
            routes: [{
                // This handler is executed when you navigate back to the history state on the path "page"
                path : "page",
                handler : jQuery.proxy(historyPageHandler, this)
            }],
            // The default handler is executed when you navigate back to the history state with an empty hash
            defaultHandler: jQuery.proxy(historyDefaultHandler, this)
        });

        // subscribe to event bus
        var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
        bus.subscribe("nav", "to", this.navHandler, this);
        bus.subscribe("nav", "back", this.navHandler, this);
        bus.subscribe("nav", "virtual", this.navHandler, this);
    },

    navHandler: function (channelId, eventId, data) {
        if (eventId === "to") {
            this.navTo(data.id, data.data, true);
        } else if (eventId === "back") {
        //**************************************************
//          if(data && data.id){
//              this.navBack(data.id);
//          } else {
//              jQuery.sap.history.back();
//          }
            var app = this.getView().app;
            if(data.type==="master"){
                app.backMaster();

            }else if(data.type==="detail"){
                app.backDetail();

            }else{alert("back to master o detail?");};
        //**************************************************
        } else if (eventId === "virtual") {
            jQuery.sap.history.addVirtualHistory();
        } else {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("'nav' event cannot be processed. There's no handler registered for event with id: " + eventId);
        }
    },

    navTo : function (id, data, writeHistory) {

        if (id === undefined) {

            // invalid parameter
            jQuery.sap.log.error("navTo failed due to missing id");

        } else {

            var app = this.getView().app;
            // navigate in the app control
            app.to(id, "slide", data);

        }
    },

    /*
    navBack : function (id) {

        if (!id) {

            // invalid parameter
            jQuery.sap.log.error("navBack - parameters id must be given");

        } else {

            // close open popovers
            if (sap.m.InstanceManager.hasOpenPopover()) {
                sap.m.InstanceManager.closeAllPopovers();
            }

            // close open dialogs
            if (sap.m.InstanceManager.hasOpenDialog()) {
                sap.m.InstanceManager.closeAllDialogs();
                jQuery.sap.log.info("navBack - closed dialog(s)");
            }

            // ... and navigate back
            var app = this.getView().app;
            var currentId = (app.getCurrentPage()) ? app.getCurrentPage().getId() : null;
            if (currentId !== id) {
                app.backToPage(id);
                jQuery.sap.log.info("navBack - back to page: " + id);
            }
        }
    }
    */
});
```

Comment: Can you show a particular route invocation?

Comment: I think the underscore could be a problem. You can either encode your id_line with encodeURIComponent() before or simply remove the _ from your route. See [navTo](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Router.html#navTo) about it. Can you test this for you?

Comment: no,underscore isn't the problem. I have tried to nat to "menu" target (without params-attribute) and I have the same error:
`2015-07-16 13:41:05 hash format error! The current Hash: /menu -`

Comment: Ok, it was just a first guess. Could you create a minimal JSBin which reproduces the this?

Comment: I just saw, that your error comes from `jQuery.sap.history`. Are you using it somewhere? Do you have a custom router implementation?

Comment: no, I have not  a  custom router

Comment: can you search your project for `jQuery.sap.history` usage?

Comment: I have updated my Q: yes, I use jQuery.sap.history but not a custom routing... App is the view that I use when I want instantiate my splitApp but if i'm in debug only the JSView functions are called, not the controller of the view (that  I have added in Q)

Comment: Ok, but why are you using routing and jQuery.sap.history at the same time? The routing should replace the jQuery.sap.history API. See [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.history.html) for more.

Comment: thankyou @TimGerlach , I found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Component.js I had 2 rows where I set up custom myNavBack and myNavToWithoutHash functions:

```
// 3a. monkey patch the router
var oRouter = this.getRouter();
oRouter.myNavBack = ui5bp.MyRouter.myNavBack; //to comment
oRouter.myNavToWithoutHash = ui5bp.MyRouter.myNavToWithoutHash; //to comment
```

I have started from an example of app skeleton for my app and then I have implemented the routing with the logic suggested from the framework.
This coexistence of two different methods to navigate produced the error in console. Tahnkyou @TimGerlach
After the comment of the two rows errors have vanished.